# Inline suppressing of warnings with Github CodeQL

Tags: python, suppress-warnings, static-code-analysis, codeql

CodeQL reports some true and some false positive for a specific rule.

Is there a way to mark a Python codeline so that the check is ignored by CodeQL?

Similar, for example to `# noqa` for Python flake or pep-8 checks.

Comment: Looks like this is [not supported at the moment](https://github.com/github/codeql/issues/11427)

Comment: @Marcono1234, that could be a valid answer (at least until the feature is added in CodeQL)

Answer (score 1):

Check out one alternative using the open source project [advanced-security/dismiss-alerts](https://github.com/advanced-security/dismiss-alerts).  It introduces an additional CodeQL query to extract out `//codeql[py/line-too-long]` or `# noqa` style comments in your code (see [test.py](https://github.com/github/codeql/blob/ededd466cb6301edc60115b9431b3909903f7fa4/python/ql/test/query-tests/analysis/suppression/test.py#L68-L75)). Those comments are then fed into the SARIF `suppression[]` object and dismissed in Code Scanning by calling the GitHub alerts api.